# migrating Jekyll 3.8.6 to 4.0 captured variables from import no longer expand

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, static-site

I have a Jekyll site with articles about products. At the top of each `post.md` I include a file with `{%- include vars -%}`. `vars` is an include file that contains `{%- include varfiles/product.html id=page.product -%}`. It automatically grabs the product number into the page, and then passes it to `product.html` in the `varfiles` folder. The following is `product.html`

```
{%- assign product = site.data.products | where:"id",include.id | first -%}

<!-- product name -->
{%- if product.name -%}
  {%- capture product-name -%}
    {{ product.name }}
  {%- endcapture -%}
{%- endif -%}


plus a lot more similar to the code above
```

The file is essentially many types of variable name creators based on the product properties pulled from the products data file, which is a list of products. The result is when I add the `{%- include vars -%}` at the top of any `post.md` it will automatically generate easier to remember/use variables names based on the product id number in the frontmatter. Then I can include the variable names throughout the article like `{{ product-name }}` and it automatically resolves from the variables that were created from the `vars` include.

THE PROBLEM: Whne I upgrade jekyll to use 4.0 all of the variables are empty. When putting `{{ product-name }}` somewhere in `post.md` under the `vars` include it would automatically convert it to the products name. On 4.0 it becomes empty. The only change I'm making is updating to Jekyll 4.0. If I downgrade all the variables work fine.

Comment: I've reproduced this one and it's a Jekyll bug. You can fill a bug here : https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md&title=

Comment: That's dope thanks for verifying. I'll submit an issue when I have a moment

Comment: It seems that this bug is addressed by [this patch](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/7878). Just have to wait for a new release.

Comment: ahhhhh awesome. my workaround moved me forward, but happy to hear they're still working this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround that seems to work is to change

`{%- assign product = site.data.products | where:"id",include.id | first -%}`

to

`{%- assign product = site.data.products[include.id] -%}`

no clue why that works.